# 'Append' a value to a dictionary for a specific key

Tags: python, string

I want to store and group different entities on a dictionary given a sentence, their indices in the sentence and entity type.

I have a string like:

```
text = "My name is David and I live in Miami, but I was born in San Francisco"
```

And I want to replace entities PERSON and LOCATION in this string via indices, with the following information.

```
entities = ['PERSON','LOCATION','LOCATION']
start = [11,31,56]
end = [16,36,69]
```

I've tried this:

```
def replace_by_index(text: str, entities: List ,start: List,end: List,):
    entities_dict = {}
    tmp = []
    for ent,st,ed in zip(entities,start,end):
        entities_dict[ent] = text[st:ed]
        
    return entities_dict
```

Which obviously doesn't work... Because the first Location gets overwritten!

```
{'PERSON': 'David', 'LOCATION': 'San Francisco'}
```

I don't want to use the values of the entities for the logic! statements like:

```
if ent == 'PERSON':
   #logic
```

This would not work in this case! I want something that could work like this:

```
def replace_by_index(text: str, entities: List ,start: List,end: List,):
    entities_dict = {}
    tmp = []
    for ent,st,ed in zip(entities,start,end):
        entities_dict[ent] = tmp.append(text[st:ed])
        
    return entities_dict
```

This one returns:

```
{'PERSON': None, 'LOCATION': None}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
{'PERSON': ['David'], 'LOCATION': ['Miami','San Francisco']}
```

This is the approach I'm taking to solve a problem and my problem is replacing all entities at the same time given the indices. If I have this dictionary my next step would be to replace the words by their respective entities with `string.replace()`. Maybe there's a better approach?

The end goal would be to end up with a string like:

"My name is PERSON_0 and I live in LOCATION_0, but I was born in LOCATION_2"

Comment: What exactly is the result you are trying to get in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
r = entities_dic.get(ent,[])
r.append(text[st:ed])
entities_dict[ent] =  r
```

A better approach is to create a dictionary

(start, end): entity

Loop over your sentence tokens.

Replace text[start, end] with dic[(start, end)] where dict is what you create.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with InfoLearner. It is much easier to set up the dictionary then append to it later. Here is another way to do it.

```
text = "My name is David and I live in Miami, but I was born in San Francisco"
entities = ['PERSON', 'LOCATION', 'LOCATION']
start = [11, 31, 56]
end = [16, 36, 69]
entities_dict = {ent: [] for ent in set(entities)}  # set up dictionary
for st, ed, ent in zip(start, end, entities):
    entities_dict[ent].append(text[st:ed])  # append the slice to the item with the appropriate entity
print(entities_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'LOCATION': ['Miami', 'San Francisco'], 'PERSON': ['David']}
```